# I have Tortoise SVN Repository on one PC how to connect this from another PC?

Tags: java, eclipse, tortoisesvn

I have Tortoise SVN repository on my PC how to connect another laptop to this Repository? Can ny one tell me the step wise procedure using Eclips?

Answer (score 0):

There is no tortoise plugin for eclipse out there. you will have to do a workaround with one of the eclipse plugins subversive or subclipse. They will offer you the "same" possibilities you have when using tortoise (but inside eclipse ;) ).

Maybe you are interested in ContextQuickie. It adds a command to eclipse which opens a tortoise monitor. (CTRL+3 -> type "tortoise) But i think this won't help you much.

To share your repositories between different PC's i would suggest to use [yatta profiles](https://www.yatta.de/profiles/). It's a tool that enables you to upload an eclipse and easily download it on another machine (containing the same plugins and repositores).

For the case that you are interested, i created a simple profile with ContextQuickie and Subclipse installed - so you can try out both. You can find it here: [Profile Eclipse with tortoise (context quickie) + svn](https://www.yatta.de/profiles/hub/m9kF). (CTRL+3 -> type "svn" and open the svn repository view to add a repo)

This is a public profile, so everyone can access it. You can keep a profile private if you wish to. Just configure it on the online profile page. (the tool will never upload any login credentials ;) )

Comment: No its not like that....I have installed SVN plugins in Eclips to connect the eclips with SVN repository and its working fine on my PC but there is another PC on same network I want to connect the Eclips running on that PC to connect on my PC's Repository. There will be some changes I think in Tortoise SVN repository.

Comment: okay maybe I'm not getting it: did you host your repository anywhere? if the repository is only stored locally on the first PC the second one can't access it. (well maybe if you would share the folder in your network but that's not the best idea i think ;) )